# Details prompt by the us to the user ( via php coding ) isn't showing up in MySQL database ( localhost )

Tags: php, mysql

I recently wrote a php code that prompts the user to key in their name, email, website, comments and gender ( I'm using php coding ). When the user has already key-ed in their data, the data is supposed to show up in my local host MySQL database ( phpmyadmin ). But the problem here is that no matter where I put the INSERT INTO function, the data that the user key-ed in, isn't being inserted into the table in phpmyadmin.. Yes, I've managed to create the table ( using php codes ) but the details doesn't seem to be inserted into the table that I've created.

Here are my codes :

```
<?php
    include "header.php";
    include "lib/db.php";
    include "module/functions.php";

    error_reporting(0);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">

    <?php
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
        $gender = "";
        $comment = "";
        $website = "";
    ?>

    <center>
    <table border="13" width="400" height="400">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="blue">guest's information</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">E-mail: </td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Website: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Comment: </td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="65"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right">Gender: </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender"<?php if ($gender=="female"); ?> value="female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender"<?php if ($gender=="male"); ?> value="male">Male
        <td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></td>
        </tr>


<?php
    include "config.inc.php";
?>

<?php
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $website = $_POST['website'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO myguests (name, email, website, comment, gender)
            VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')";   

    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($name !="" && $email !="" && $website !="" && $comment !="" && $gender !="") {
            $query = "INSERT INTO myguests (name, email, website, comment, gender)
                        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')";

        echo "You've entered the data.";


        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Yo brother, sudah la brother.")';
        echo '</script>';

        } else {

            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Yo brother, fuck off. Isi elok-elok la brother.")';
            echo '</script>';       
        }
    } 


    ?>  
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

and here is my configuration codes ( that connects to the localhost database )

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    //Set connection time limit/memory limit to infinity/unlimited
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "first_test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50),
        website VARCHAR(100),
        comment VARCHAR(420),
        gender VARCHAR(6)
        )";

        $name = "";
        $email = "";
        $website = "";
        $comment = "";
        $gender = "" ;

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "<br><br>Table MyGuests created successfully";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO myguests (name, email, website, comment, gender)
                VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {   
        echo "<br><br>Guest's data is inserted successfully into the database<br><br>";
    } else {
            echo "<br><br>Fail to insert guest's data into the database<br><br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thank you and have a nice day.

p/s I am fully aware of the SQL injection. I'm just starting to learn about php coding and databases, so I'm running it on localhost only. Not gonna use it for any other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually here:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($name !="" && $email !="" && $website !="" && $comment !="" && $gender !="") {
            $query = "INSERT INTO myguests (name, email, website, comment, gender)
                        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')";

        echo "You've entered the data.";


        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Yo brother, sudah la brother.")';
        echo '</script>';

        }
```

You're actually building the string, but not passing to the database to query it.

What you actually missing is this line:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Amend the code:

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO myguests (name, email, website, comment, gender)
                        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo "You've entered the data.";
```

Comment: I've already inserted the `$result = mysql_query($query);` into the part, but nonetheless the user-prompted details still doesn't gets inserted into the localhost phpmyadmin database.. Is it possible because there's some setting error in the phpmyadmin that doesn't allow me to insert the data into the database?